# How to show indicator while doing HTTP request in swift

Tags: swift, httprequest

I'm trying to show label and indicator while sending HTTP request in swift, but action on label and indicator is always done after HTTP request finishes.

So the indicator and label shows after whole httpRequest is done, just before performing segue. It is visible for miliseconds not for whole waiting time.

Here's the code. On button pressed, I want to show indicator and label, that are hidden by default, and then invoke HTTP request.

```
class NewVisitViewController: UIViewController, DownloadInfoProtocol {
let dispatchGroupController : DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

@IBOutlet var downloadSpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet var downloadLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func showAllNewVisits(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showDownloadInfo()

    let dataBaseManager = DataBaseManager()
    availableVistis = dataBaseManager.getAllFreeVisits()

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showAllVisitsSeque", sender: self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    hideDownloadInfo()
}

func hideDownloadInfo(){
    self.downloadLabel.isHidden = true
    self.downloadSpinner.isHidden = true
}

func showDownloadInfo(){
    self.downloadLabel.isHidden = false
    self.downloadSpinner.isHidden = false
}
```

And the code in dataBaseManager, that actually makes HTTP request:

```
func getAllFreeVisits() -> [Visit] {
    print("getAllFreeVisits")
    let params: NSDictionary = [
        "entity" : "getAllFreeVisits"
    ]
    return getVisitsWithGivenParams(params: params)
}


func getVisitsWithGivenParams(params: NSDictionary) -> [Visit]  {

    print("getWithParams")
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    var vistis : [Visit] = []

    let finalURL = appendQueryParams(params: params)
    guard let url = URL(string: finalURL) else {
        print ("error while creationg URL")
        return vistis
    }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
    {
        (data, response, error) in
        let jsonData = Data(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!.utf8)

        do {
            vistis = try self.decoder.decode([Visit].self, from: jsonData) 
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    })
    task.resume()

    dispatchGroup.wait()
    return vistis
}
```

I guess it's something with multithreading, but I have not idea what should be changed here in order to show indicator and label before starting HTTP request invocation.

Comment: You have to show/hide loading indicator before hit request to API or till get the response from the server?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav I want to show indicator before doing requests - thus it should be visible for all time, that request takes.

Comment: You can check my answer, I hope it resolved your issue!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `completion` handler to get know when the `http` request is finished. Then you can hide the activity indicator and label and also perform the `segue`.

You have to update the `getVisitsWithGivenParams` method as below,

```
func getVisitsWithGivenParams(params: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (([Visit], Error?) -> Void)) {

    let finalURL = appendQueryParams(params: params)
    guard let url = URL(string: finalURL) else {
        print ("error while creationg URL")
        completion(nil, NSError()) 
        return
    }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
    {
        (data, response, error) in
        let jsonData = Data(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!.utf8)

        do {
            let vistis = try self.decoder.decode([Visit].self, from: jsonData)
            completion(visits, nil) 
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil, error) 
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Now you can use this as below,

```
@IBAction func showAllNewVisits(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showDownloadInfo()

    let params: [String: Any] = ["entity" : "getAllFreeVisits"]
    let dataBaseManager = DataBaseManager()
    dataBaseManager.getVisitsWithGivenParams(params: params) { (visits, error) in
        self.hideDownloadInfo()

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        self.availableVistis = visits
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showAllVisitsSeque", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for anwsering, but it didn't help. Problem is not with **hidding** label and indicator after https request is done, but** showing it before request invocation**. So even after implementing yours changes, indicator and label do not show before invocation - which I totally don't understand...

Comment: I have already tried that - and if there is only  showDownloadInfo() in showAllNewVisits method - than the indicator and label shows after pressing the button. When I add invocation of getAllFreeVisits that invokes requests - it stopts working - label and indicator shows after request is done, so there are visible on screen for miliseconds before segue is performed.

Comment: Now the thing is if the request is not taking much time then this is a normal behavior, right? If you are able to see these views and they are getting hidden just before showing the next screen then why you want to show? Are they hiding before the request is completed?

Comment: No, request take about 2-3 seconds. Behaviour with previeously given code is following:
1. I press button, indicator is not showed.
2. Requests starts, indicator is not showed.
3. Requests finishes, indicator is not showed.
4. Indicator shows, it is visible for miliseconds
5. Segue is invoked, new View is loaded.

Comment: Then please show this method `@IBAction func showAllNewVisits(_ sender: UIButton)` by editing your question as i have doubt that you might be invoking segue immediately after making the request. If you use the above method same as i have then you will see indicator and label for 2-3 seconds.